# Json: how to to add an avg to get the average

Tags: json, laravel

I have a function that displays the 'tarificationtaches' list i would like to add an avg to get the average 'techniciens' moyenne_avis from tables avis_intervention where "intervention.technicien_id" = "tarificationtaches.techncien_id" , in this is my schema .

**taches_table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('taches', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('libelle_tache');
        $table->float('Tarif', 8,2)->nullable();
        $table->integer('metier_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('metier_id')->references('id')->on('metiers');
        $table->datetime('deleted_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**tarificationtaches_tables**

```
Schema::create('tarificationtaches', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->float('tarif', 8,2);
    $table->integer('tache_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('tache_id')->references('id')->on('taches');
    $table->integer('technicien_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('technicien_id')->references('id')->on('techniciens');
    $table->datetime('deleted_at')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**techniciens_tables**

```
    Schema::create('techniciens', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->boolean('actif')->default(1);
    $table->float('moyenne_avis')->nullable();
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->datetime('deleted_at')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();

});
```

**avis_interventions_tables**

```
    Schema::create('avis_interventions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('qualité');
    $table->integer('nbr_heure');
    $table->string('service');
    $table->float('note', 1,1);
    $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients');
    $table->integer('intervention_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('intervention_id')->references('id')->on('interventions');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**interventions_tables**

```
    Schema::create('interventions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->date('date_intervention')->nullable();
    $table->string('description');
    $table->dateTime('duree_prevu');
    $table->boolean('statut');
    $table->integer('technicien_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('technicien_id')->references('id')->on('techniciens');
    $table->integer('tarification_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('tarification_id')->references('id')->on('tarificationtaches');
    $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('Clients');


    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**this is my function**

```
 public function getTar(){
 $tarifications = tarificationtache::with('technicien')->get();

    return $tarifications->map(function ($tarification) {
        return [
            'nom' => $tarification->technicien->user->nom,
            'moyenne_avis' => $tarification->technicien->moyenne_avis,
            'tache' => $tarification->tache->libelle_tache,
            'tarif' => $tarification->tarif,
        ];
    });    


   }
```

**it shown like this**

```
[{"nom":"tech 1","moyenne_avis":null,"tache":"tache 2","tarif":29.55}, 
{"nom":"tech   
2","moyenne_avis":null,"tache":"tache 3","tarif":55.12},{"nom":"tech 
1","moyenne_avis":null,"tache":"tache 3","tarif":253},{"nom":"tech 
2","moyenne_avis":null,"tache":"tache 3","tarif":28.22}]
```

[image]

Comment: What is your expected JSON? And you have not provided `taches` table schema, please provide.

Comment: @RaviManiyar please see above, i've added the "tache" schema. I have interventions and each intervention has avis_intervention and each intervention is dedicated to a single technician I want to display the average of the avis_intervention where intervention. technician id = tarificationtache.techncien-id

Comment: @RaviManiyar i would like to also calculate the average of "note" from the table avis $table->float('note', 1,1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public function getTar(){
     $tarifications = tarificationtache::with('technicien')->get();

        return $tarifications->map(function ($tarification) {
            return [
                'nom' => $tarification->technicien->user->nom,
                'tache' => $tarification->tache_id,
                'tarif' => $tarification->tarif,
                'avg_avis_interventions' => $tarification->technicien- 
                 >avisinterventions->avg('note')
            ];
        }); 

        print_r($results -> toJson());   
        exit;

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

Below are the model files followed by model relationships eloquent query which I have used to generate the output:

**technicien model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\User;

class technicien extends Model
{
    protected $table = "techniciens";

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

---

**tarificationtache model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\technicien;
use App\tache;
use App\interventions;

class tarificationtache extends Model
{
    protected $table = "tarificationtaches";

    public function technicien()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\technicien', 'technicien_id', 'id');
    }

    public function tache()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\tache', 'tache_id', 'id');
    }

    public function interventions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\interventions', 'technicien_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

---

**tache model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class tache extends Model
{
   protected $table = "taches";
}
```

---

**interventions model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\avis_interventions;

class interventions extends Model
{
   protected $table = "interventions";

   public function avis_interventions()
   {
        return $this->hasMany('App\avis_interventions', 'intervention_id', 'id');
   }
}
```

---

**avis_interventions model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class avis_interventions extends Model
{
   protected $table = "avis_interventions";
}
```

**Model relationship query:**

```
$tarifications = tarificationtache::with('technicien')->get();

$results = $tarifications->map(function ($tarification) {
    return [
        'nom' => $tarification->technicien->user->name,
        'moyenne_avis' => $tarification->technicien->moyenne_avis,
        'tache' => $tarification->tache->libelle_tache,
        'tarif' => $tarification->tarif,
        'avg_avis_interventions' => $tarification -> interventions -> count()
    ];
}); 

print_r($results -> toJson());   
exit;
```

That returns below output to me:

```
[{
    "nom": "Ravi-carpenter",
    "moyenne_avis": 2,
    "tache": "Task #1",
    "tarif": 5.22,
    "avg_avis_interventions": 2
}, {
    "nom": "Ravi-carpenter",
    "moyenne_avis": 3.5,
    "tache": "Task #2",
    "tarif": 6.52,
    "avg_avis_interventions": 3
}]
```

Comment: i have this error "Call to a member function count() on null"

Comment: I will post my model files today once I have access to my PC.

Comment: @IT2704 - I have posted my models as well. Let me know if that helps. Thanks.

Comment: i have this error  ('Call to a member function count() on null"')

Comment: Are the tables empty? Because I did not get chance to test with empty dataset. But when I have proper data in my tables then this works.

Comment: i have many inset on table but i think the message display syntax error because it has no attribute to calculate !.?

Comment: Can you please post screenshot of Laravel detailed error here?

Comment: i have added   the screen

Comment: Thanks for the snap. Sorry to tell you but can you make sure that the spelling of "interventions" is same in the controller as well as on the model function?

Comment: in have chaged to "'avg_avis_interventions' => $tarification ->intervention -> count()" it work but he shown me like that (([{"nom":null,"moyenne_avis":null,"tache":"tache 2","tarif":29.55,"avg_avis_interventions":1},{"nom":null,"moyenne_avis":null,"tache":"tache 3","tarif":55.12,"avg_avis_interventions":0},{"nom":null,"moyenne_avis":null,"tache":"tache 3","tarif":253,"avg_avis_interventions":0},{"nom":null,"moyenne_avis":null,"tache":"tache 3","tarif":28.22,"avg_avis_interventions":1}]))

Comment: nom is null and i like to shown the average of "note" from table avis_intervention